# Can we pass conditional parameters to fixture functions in pytest?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures

I want to pass a list as a parameter to fixture based on a if condition. Is there a way to do this?

For example, please see the following code.

What I want to achieve is that if I pass odd as the num type in command line argument in pytest, the list passed as parameter to the fixture should be odd numbers and even numbers for argument even.

P.S I am using pytest-xdist to run this tests multiple times, hence I use sys.stderr to print output.

**filename: conftest.py**

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--type', action='store', help='Number of times to repeat each test')
```

**filename: test_file.py**

```
import pytest, sys

lis = []

@pytest.fixture()
def nested_fixture(pytestconfig):
    global lis
    numtype = str(pytestconfig.getoption("type"))

    if numtype == "odd":
        lis.append(1)
        lis.append(3)

    if numtype == "even":
        lis.append(2)
        lis.append(4)

    return lis

@pytest.fixture(params = nested_fixture)
def fixture_function(request):
    return request.param


def test_function(fixture_function):
    print >> sys.stderr , fixture_function
```

I execute this using the following command in terminal

```
pytest -sv -n 2 --type odd
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on my [previous anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67636821/3220988) for the question [*Filtering pytest fixtures*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780376/filtering-pytest-fixtures).

If you require a certain degree of logic to determine which parameters to apply to each test, you might want to consider using the `pytest_generate_tests` [hook.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example)

The hook function `pytest_generate_tests` is called for every collected test. The `metafunc` argument allows you to dynamically parametrize each individual test case. Rewriting `test_file.py` to use `pytest_generate_tests` could look like this:

```
import sys

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "fixture_function" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        parameters = []
        if metafunc.config.getoption("type") == "odd":
            parameters += [1, 3]
        elif metafunc.config.getoption("type") == "even":
            parameters += [2, 4]
        metafunc.parametrize("fixture_function", parameters)

def test_function(fixture_function):
    print(fixture_function, file=sys.stderr)
```

In combination with your existing `conftest.py`code, even add odd test parameters can be controlled via the `--type` command-line option:

```
$ pytest -v test_file.py --type odd
===== test session starts =====
…
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

test_file.py::test_function[1] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                        [ 50%]
test_file.py::test_function[3] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                        [100%]

===== 2 passed in 0.02s =====


$ pytest -v test_file.py --type even
===== test session starts =====
…
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

test_file.py::test_function[2] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                        [ 50%]
test_file.py::test_function[4] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                        [100%]

===== 2 passed in 0.01s =====
```